# Рисование линии в WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

В WPF есть возможность использовать PathGeometry как траекторию движения объекта. А что, если надо, чтобы вместо движения объекта рисовалась линия? Как такое можно осуществить? В идеале, конечно, надо чтобы объект постепенно проявлялся. Пока в голову пришло только рисование по точкам при анимации невидимого объекта, который движется по траектории

Comment: Вот это по идее должно работать: http://jimmangaly.blogspot.com/2009/04/wpf-text-to-animated-path.html

Comment: Хотя там тоже решение в виде рисования по точкам.